# Provided id of the wrong type for classname Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I am Using spring security for my project but named user' entity primary key column id type bigint in database. This entity id type long.   These types are compatible. But project wrong "com.app.model.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String". User entity id column long to string wants me to change.

---

User Model

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user")
 public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public User() {

}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

public Long getUserid() {
    return id;
}

public void setUserid(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
private boolean enabled;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<UserRole> userRoles;

//getter setter
```

---

UserRole Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UserRole() {

}

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
@MapsId("user_id")
public User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Role.class)
@MapsId("role_id")
private Role role;

//getter setter
```

---

Role Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class Role implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "role_name")
private String roleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
FetchType.LAZY)
private List<UserRole> userRoles;

//getter setter
```

---

UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {

public UserDetailsServiceImp() {
}

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.app.model.User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }

    User securityUser = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), 
true, true, true, true,
            buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoles()));
    return securityUser;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(List<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole().getRoleName()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> results = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    return results;
}
```

}

---

Security Config

```
 @ComponentScan("com.app")
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/").permitAll().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/main").failureUrl("/login-status-error")
            .permitAll().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().csrf();
}

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    // auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

---

App Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.app")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

@Autowired
public AppConfig() {

}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    logger.info("Building session factory...");

    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    sessionFactory.setDataSource(getApplicationDataSource());

    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.app.model");

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.app.config.CustomPostgreSQLDialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults","false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema","public");

    //Caching
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics","false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class","infinispan");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg","org/infinispan/hibernate/cache/commons/builder/infinispan-configs-local.xml");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode","ENABLE_SELECTIVE");

    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    logger.info("Session factory builded successfully...");

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean("applicationDataSource")
public DataSource getApplicationDataSource() {
    logger.info("Initializing data source...");
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vbs_db");
    ds.setUsername("postgres");
    ds.setPassword("postgress");
    ds.setConnectionTimeout(Integer.parseInt("20000"));
    ds.setMinimumIdle(Integer.parseInt("5"));
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt("20"));
    ds.setIdleTimeout(Integer.parseInt("300000"));
    return ds;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

---

ApplicationServletInitializer

```
public class ApplicationServletInitializer extends 
 AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class, AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}
```

---

Pom XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>VeterinerBilgiSistemi</groupId>
<artifactId>VeterinerBilgiSistemi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRİNG -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HİBERNATE -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- CACHE -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- PostgreSQL -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

Login JSP

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>VBS GİRİŞ PANELİ</h3>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end social_icon">
                <span><i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form name='login' action="${context}/login" method='POST'>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">

                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Parola">
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center remember">
                    <input type="checkbox">Beni Hatırla
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Giriş" class="btn float-right login_btn">
                </div>
            </form>
                <c:if test="${not empty errorMessge}"><div style="color:red; font-weight: bold;
                 margin: 30px 0px;">${errorMessge}</div></c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I added it. (App Config-ApplicationServletInitializer-PomXML-Login Jsp)

Comment: As requested before please add the stacktrace. Also writing 2 sentences and dumping all your code here isn't a proper way of asking a question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.